# Add column to BOM lines in OpenERP v8

Tags: python, xml, odoo, openerp-8

I'm trying to customize the BOM form view with a custom column in the BOM lines, based on https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/7.0/mrp_bom_product_details/

My attempt stranded at the following state:

**custom_bom_form.py:**

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv
from openerp.tools.translate import _

class mrp_bom(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'mrp.bom'

    _columns ={
        'product_qty_available': fields.related('product_id', 'qty_available', type='float', string='Quantity On Hand', readonly=True),
    }
    _defaults = {
    } 

mrp_bom()
```

**custom_bom_form.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<openerp>
    <data>

        <record id="mrp_bom_form_view_product_details" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">mrp.bom.form.product_details</field>
            <field name="model">mrp.bom</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="mrp.mrp_bom_form_view"/>    
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//notebook/page[@string='Components']/field/tree[@string='Components']/field[@name='product_qty']" position="after" >
                    <field name="product_qty_available" />
                </xpath> 
            </field>
        </record>

    </data>
</openerp>
```

This results in an error from Odoo while installing the module:

```
ParseError: "ValidateError
Field(s) `arch` failed against a constraint: Invalid view definition

Error details:
Field `product_qty_available` does not exist

Error context:
View `mrp.bom.form.product_details`
[view_id: 1094, xml_id: n/a, model: mrp.bom, parent_id: 675]" while parsing /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/mrp_bom_product_details/mrp_bom_product_details.xml:5, near
    <record id="mrp_bom_form_view_product_details" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">mrp.bom.form.product_details</field>
        <field name="model">mrp.bom</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="mrp.mrp_bom_form_view"/>    
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//notebook/page[@string='Components']/field/tree[@string='Components']/field[@name='product_qty']" position="after">
                <field name="product_qty_available"/>
            </xpath> 
        </field>
    </record>
```

I can't figure out why I can't reference `product_qty_available` there, it works from other places in the BOM form. E.g.:

```
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="product_id" position="after">
                <field name="product_qty_available" />
            </field> 
        </field>
```

Works.

Also instead changing the referenced field to something the system knows works, E.g. adding another `product_qty` column:

```
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//notebook/page[@string='Components']/field/tree[@string='Components']/field[@name='product_qty']" position="after" >
                <field name="product_qty" />
            </xpath> 
        </field>
```

Can someone show me what I am doing wrong. How can I reference `product_qty_available` there? Is there something special about the notebook page?

**Update**

Working py file:

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv
from openerp.tools.translate import _

class mrp_bom_line(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'mrp.bom.line'

    _columns ={
        'product_qty_available': fields.related('product_id', 'qty_available', type='float', string='Quantity On Hand', readonly=True),
    }
    _defaults = {
    }

mrp_bom_line()
```

and xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<openerp>
    <data>

        <record id="mrp_bom_form_view_product_details" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">mrp.bom.form.product_details</field>
            <field name="model">mrp.bom</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="mrp.mrp_bom_form_view"/>    
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//field[@name='bom_line_ids']/tree/field[@name='product_qty']" position="after">
                    <field name="product_qty_available" />
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>

    </data>
</openerp>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added the field `product_qty_available` in the model `mrp.bom` and you are trying to add the field in the inside the field `bom_line_ids` - in the tree view of `bom_line_ids` which is one2many of `mbrp.bom.line`, so system tries to find the field `product_qty_available` over there in `mrp.bom.line` model which is actually not there.

I am not sure, what is your exact aim but, try the following

1.The field is added in the model `mrp.bom` so you should try the
    following

```
<xpath expr="/form/group/group[1]/field[@name='product_id']" position="after">
    <field name="product_qty_available"/>
</xpath>
```

so this will add field after `product_id` field in the top section of screen where it shows master information.

2.Add the field in the `mrp.bom.line` model and then try the following:

```
<xpath expr="//field[@name='bom_line_ids']/tree/field[@name='product_qty']"  position="after">
    <field name="product_qty_available"/>
</xpath>
```

Comment: Your second suggestion is what I'm trying to accomplish, but no luck yet. I changed the .py file to define the mrp_bom_line class inherited from mrp.bom.line, and changed the xml file with your second suggestion. Odoo then still reports that `product_qty_available` does not exist.

Comment: can you post your code here for that ".py" file. Did you restarted the server and updated the module?

Comment: If I also change the model to mrp.bom.line in the xml file, Odoo gives the error that 'Field `message_follower_ids` does not exist'.

Comment: if possible edit your question and post the latest updates that you have made for .py and .xml file.

Comment: I restarted the server and did an 'Update module list' and now it works! I did try that with some of my attempts, but didn't think it was really needed since the module was never actually installed, so stopped doing it. Is there some logic behind when I should either of those two, or should I just always do that?

I have one more question: How do you tell that `product_qty_available` needs to be in a `mrp.bom.line` inherited class?

Comment: Whenever you do any kind of changes in ".py" file you must restart the server, otherwise the change will not come into affect. If you made any of the changes in ".py" or ".xml" which leads to changes in database than you must restart the module and update the module. If do any of the change in ".xml" than you don't need to restart the server but need to update the module to update the database. About the `mrp.bom.line`, I got the idea from your given `xpath` expression showing that you wanted to add the field in bom line but by mistake you added it in the `mrp.bom` .